# How to retrieve secret key from Azure Key Vault in React JS

Tags: reactjs, azure-keyvault

How can I fetch the secret key from azure key vault in reactjs application? I am passing my secret key in headers like below

```
 headers: {
  "subscription-key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "content-type": "application/json"
  }
```

How can I get the "subscription-key" value from azure key vault? I added my subscription-key value in the azure key vault.

Comment: Try to request the API to see:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getkey/getkey

Comment: Any update now? If it helps you, please accept it as asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

In local, you can sue `loginWithServicePrincipalSecret` with clientid and secret to get the credential.

```
function getKeyVaultCredentials(){
    return msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(clientId, secret, domain);
}

function getKeyVaultSecret(credentials) {
    let keyVaultClient = new KeyVault.KeyVaultClient(credentials);
    return keyVaultClient.getSecret(KEY_VAULT_URI, 'secret', "");
}

getKeyVaultCredentials().then(
    getKeyVaultSecret
).then(function (secret){
    console.log(`Your secret value is: ${secret.value}.`);
}).catch(function (err) {
    throw (err);
});
```

Also, you could use the `loginWithAppServiceMSI()` method from `ms-rest-azure` will autodetect if you're on a WebApp and get the token from the MSI endpoint. So you must host your code on Azure webapp. Refer to [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-node/) for more details.

```
function getKeyVaultCredentials(){
    return msRestAzure.loginWithAppServiceMSI({resource: 'https://vault.azure.net'});   
}
```

Comment: Getting Error: EnvironmentCredential is not supported in the browser.

Comment: The error is intended- the DefaultAzureCredential() is supported in Node, but not client-side Javascript

The primary reason for this is because it's usually a serious security hole to expose your clientKey to anyone browsing your site.